# Compute image pixel differences in efficient way

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, pixel

Say I have a 24 x 24 image as a numpy array.

I want to compute the pixel differences between each pixel and all the other pixels in the image, excluding that pixel. That will give me (24 * 24) * (24 * 24 -1) values.

How do I do this outside of a loop and in an efficient manner?

Example:

Array of image:

```
[[1,5],
[8,3]]
```

Differences:

```
Pixel 1 (Value = 1) : [-4,-7,-2]
Pixel 2 (Value = 5) :  [4,-3,2]
Pixel 3 (Value = 8): [7,3,5]
Pixel 4 (Value = 3):[2,-2,-5]
```

End Result:

```
[-4, -7, -2, 4, -3, 2, 7, 3, 5, 2, -2, -5]
```

Comment: Could you give a short example? Such as `array` and `other_array` will be computed to `answer`. The arrays can be small, say 2x2 or 3x3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
ret = img.ravel()
ret = ret[:,None] - ret

mask = np.arange(len(ret)) != np.arange(len(ret))[:,None]
# masking
ret[np.where(mask)]
```

Output:

```
array([-4, -7, -2,  4, -3,  2,  7,  3,  5,  2, -2, -5])
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: I've tried to implement it a couple times (both on my local machine and on Google Collab), and it takes up all the RAM in both, and then crashes.
Any trick to fix this?

Comment: This probably because your image is not 24x24?

Comment: Yes, it's actually 178x218, I just realized it. I'll try and resize the image

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to have some zeros in your array, you can create a 4D array that tells you the difference between pixel `[i, j]` and  in the original array`[m, n]` at location `[i, j, m, n]`. You will have zeros at along the diagonalwhere  ai == m and j == n`, butyou can always mask that out or get rid of it in other ways:

```
img[..., None, None] - img[None, None, ...]
```